# Linux file names & file globbing

Tags: linux, filenames, glob

I have a list of files named:

file000
file001
file002
file003
...
file1100

How can I match all files that have a number greater than 800 but less than 1000 ?
I am using linux bash

Thank you

---

### Edit

Actually, my files are named like:
ab869.enc
cp936.enc
g122345.enc
x2022.enc
abc8859-14.enc
aax5601.enc
cp936-1.enc

so the first solution dont match the correct files :(

How can I match files that have number between 800-999 ?

Comment: Using magic?  Or do you have a programming language / shell in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*[89][0-9][0-9].enc
```

That uses Bash's "pathname expansion" feature (aka "globbing") to match all files ending with a number between 800 and 999 followed by ".enc". (This is not a regular expression).

For example, using the above expression you can do this in your script:

```
mv *[89][0-9][0-9].enc path/to/destination/
```

If you need it to also match a file named like "cp850-1.enc", then you would need to change the expression to:

```
*[89][0-9][0-9]*.enc
```

Comment: Just to add on to this, if you happen to be using zsh, you can shorten this to [89][0-99], or [0-N] where N is any number. I thought this would work in bash, but it appears not to. It really depends on the character set the shell's regex engine uses.

Answer (score 5):

In shell, try this:

```
ls file{801..999}
```

This will list the files starting with `file801` and ending with `file999`.

For explanation, see the manual:

- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion

Comment: Actually,files are named like that:
ab869.enc  
cp936.enc
g122345.enc 
x2022.enc
abc8859-14.enc
aax5601.enc

so the above dont match the correct files :(
How can I match files that have number between 800-999 ?

Comment: This will expand all of the numbers, regardless of whether such a named file exists. For example, it will expand to "file801 file802 file803 ..." even if the only file that exists is "file999". Brace expansion doesn't work on file names, it just works on arbitrary strings.

Comment: @DanMoulding Definitvely - the original request was "I have files file000 through file1100, how do I select file801 through file999", for which it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

This provides an interesting expansion but can not be tested without the original files in a directory.

```
echo [a-z,A-Z]*{801..999}[a-z,A-Z]*.enc
```

There should be an asterisk after both sets of brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Take your pick.

```
ls | awk -F'[^0-9]*' '800<$2&&$2<1000'  # assuming no filenames start with number

perl -le'/(\d+)/&&800<$1&&$1<1000&&print for<*>'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is close to what you want:

```
$ ls *{800..999}{,-*}.enc

ab869.enc  abc8859-14.enc  cp936-1.enc  cp936.enc
```

The trouble is that you're picking up `abc8859-14.enc`, which you don't want. In this case, egrep will be your friend:

```
$ ls *{800..999}{,-*}.enc | egrep '[^0-9][0-9]{3}(|-.*)\.enc'
```

If you want to move or copy files, you'll probably want to wrap this expression in a `for` loop (in certain circumstances, you might be able to use xargs rather than a for loop).

```
 for file in $(ls *{800..999}{,-*}.enc | egrep '[^0-9][0-9]{3}(|-.*)\.enc')
 do
      # copy abc859-14.enc to abc859-14.bak
      basefile=$(basename $file .enc)
      cp $file "$basefile.bak"
 done
```