# Filename and File Globbing

Tags: linux, bash, match, filenames, glob

I am trying to figure out a problem and this was very helpful [Linux file names & file globbing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065164/linux-file-names-file-globbing)
but I am still having issues.

I have over a million files in my directory in my linux system. And I need to copy file with filename less than or equal to a certain number to another directory.
For example:

cp all files with filename less than  or equal to the number 29108273357520896 to another dir.

Can someone help me with this a little. The [][] thing is confusing me a lot.

Comment: Don't do this with globbing. Use `if [[ $filename < $limit ]]`.

Comment: BTW, putting a million files in a single directory is not generally a good idea. Unix filesystems are not generally well suited for such huge directories.

Comment: Ok I shall try the if. What you are saying is I should have multiple subdirectories and partition the million files into the subdir?

Comment: Yes. You should probably try to keep the number of entries in a directory below 10K.

Comment: Are all the filenames just numbers? No exensions? No variations? Just numbers?

Comment: They are .xml files. I ended up putting them all on one file to create a huge pseudo xml file with some parsing involved obviously. As Barmar mentioned, it was really slow having one million files in a directory. Thanks for the tips guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy from `dir1` to `dir2` each file that exists between `0 - 29108273357520896` fairly easily:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i maxval=29108273357520896

function usage {

cat >&2 << TAG

Copy all files from 'srcdir' to 'tgtdir' with numeric names less than 'maxname'.

    Usage:  "${0//*\//}" srcdir tgtdir [maxname]  (maxname default: $maxval) 

TAG

    exit 1
}

## test required input
if [ -z "$1" -o -z "$2" ]; then
    printf "\n error: insufficient input.\n"
    usage
fi

## assign variables
srcdir="$1"
tgtdir="$2"
declare -i maxname="${3:-$maxval}"   # default maxval

## validate srcdir
if [ ! -d "$srcdir" ]; then
    printf "\n error: source dir does not exist.\n"
    usage
fi

## validate or create tgtdir
[ -d "$tgtdir" ] || mkdir -p "$tgtdir"
if [ ! -d "$tgtdir" ]; then
    printf "\n error: tgtdir does not exist and cannot be created, check permissions.\n"
    usage
fi

## validate maxname
if [ $maxname -gt $maxval ]; then
    printf "\n error: invalid 'maxname'. value exceeds maximum allowed: %s\n" "$maxval"
    usage
fi

## for 0 - $maxname, check that file exists, if so copy to tgtdir
for ((i=0; i<$maxname; i++)); do
    [ -f "$i" ] && cp -a "${srcdir}/${i}" "${tgtdir}"
done

exit 0
```

**As a one-liner in the dir with the files**

```
for ((i=0; i<29108273357520896; i++)); do [ -f "$i" ] && cp -a "$i" "/path/to/new/dir"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question could use more context.  Specifically, why do you have a million files?  What is creating them?  While you could use some shell scripting to work with this, there might be a more efficient way by not getting in this position in the first place.

Comment: The files are xml files with tweets in them. They were converted from json to xml file for search engine indexing.

Comment: Carlise - this is **NOT** an **Answer**.  This is a **Comment**. StackOverflow is a resource where **Answers** provide **technical solution** to the posed coding problem. Your **Comment** provides no correct technical solution to anything. That's the difference between the **Your Answer** input dialog and the **add a comment** link.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Since Carlise only has one reputation-point, (s)he does not see "add a comment" links on other users' questions.

Comment: Darn, I did forget. My apologies to Calise. I guess I'm just touchy over all the terribly-poor quality comments that have been masquerading as answers since the latest semester began... Nevertheless, the comment should not have been posted as an answer.